# Linear combination of convex set is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

> A set $U$ is a **convex set** if whenever $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are points in $U$, the line segment joining $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$,$$\mathcal l(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\left\{t\mathbf x+(1-t)\mathbf y):0\leq t\leq 1 \right\},$$ is also in $U$.
>
> Let $A_i\subset\mathbb R_m$ be a convex set for $i=1,\dots,n$. Prove that the set$$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iA_i=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ia_i|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R,a_i\in A_i\right\}$$ is also convex set.

MY TRY:
Choose any two $a_{i,1},a_{i,2}$ from $A_i$, then $(t(a_{i,1})+(1-t)(a_{i,2}))\in A_i$.Then,$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i(t(a_{i,1})+(1-t)(a_{i,2}))=t\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ia_{i,1}+(1-t)\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ia_{i,2}$.

Comment: You have the right calculations, but you should start with "Let $x$ and $y$ be any two elements of the given set. Then $x = \ldots, y = \ldots$."

Comment: The definition is odd. Is $(\alpha_i)$ fixed once and for all (LHS) or not (RHS)?

Comment: Is the claim really true, i mean you can take 2 non intersecting discs in $R^2$, and a point lying in each disc but the line segment is not entirely in the union of 2 discs.

Comment: @derivative The claim is not that the union is convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And this is $s=\sum\limits_i\alpha_ib_i$ where $b_i=$ $____$. For each $i$, by convexity of $A_i$, $b_i$ belongs to $____$, hence $s$ belongs to $____$, QED.

Comment: Sir, I think, $b_i=(t(a_{i,1})+(1-t)(a_{i,2}))$, and $b_i$ belongs to $A_i$ and, $s$ belongs to $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iA_i=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ia_i|\alpha_i\in\mathbb R,a_i\in A_i\right\}$, right?